# Google Photos API issue: response without mediaItems

Tags: google-apis-explorer, google-photos-api

I have an issue getting the right response from some API methods.
When I am trying to get a list of mediaItems with `list` [method](https://developers.google.com/photos/library/reference/rest/v1/mediaItems/list), the response which I get includes only the `nextPageToken` string, but not the `mediaItems` list as expected.
I can get this behaviour either with the API Explorer or with my python code.

On the other hand, when I am trying to get a list of mediaItems with `search` [method](https://developers.google.com/photos/library/reference/rest/v1/mediaItems/search), it works just as expected.

Moreover, when I am switching to another pair of accounts, it also works.

Not working combination of accounts:

- Request from account A to get a list of mediaItems from account A
- Request from account A to get a list of mediaItems from account B
- Request from account C to get a list of mediaItems from account A
- Request from account C to get a list of mediaItems from account B

Working combinations:

- Request from account A to get a list of mediaItems from account C
- Request from account C to get a list of mediaItems from account C
- Request from account C to get a list of mediaItems from account D

Finally, for about two or three months ago, everything worked perfectly.

I hope that I was clear in my explanations.

Could it be something in the settings of the accounts (A and B)?
Any suggestions?

Thank you in advanced,
Boris

Comment: Im having the same issues, did you resolvthis issue?